# ¿Cómo ordenar un array de objecto por indice y valor en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, reduce

Tengo un array de objectos:

```
        let data = [
            {
                id: 1,
                posicion: 1,
                nombre: 'televisor'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                posicion: 2,
                nombre: 'celular'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                posicion: 3,
                nombre: 'cama'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                posicion: 4,
                nombre: 'laptop'
            },
        ]
```

y quisiera ordenarlos a través de parámetros, ejemplo:
Quiero que el item con **id = '3'** este en la posición **2** y los demás item se ordenen a partir de esa petición.

Esto estuve haciendo, lo primero es recorrer el arreglo y preguntar si el index que viene como parámetro es igual a la posición el arreglo y si es así coloca el value en el campo **posición** caso contrario coloca el índice:

```
const ordenarItems = (index, value) => {
            const rpta = data.reduce((ac, el, i) => {
                if (index === i + 1) {
                    ac.push({
                        ...el,
                        posicion: +value,
                    });
                } else {
                    ac.push({
                        ...el,
                        posicion: i + 1,
                    });
                }

                return ac;
            }, []);

            console.log(rpta);
        };
```

Esto es el resultado que quisiera obtener:

```
[
            {
                id: 1,
                posicion: 1,
                nombre: "televisor",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                posicion: 2,
                nombre: "cama",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                posicion: 3,
                nombre: "celular",
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                posicion: 4,
                nombre: "laptop",
            },
        ]
```

Gracias por el apoyo de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como conoces el indice en el que esta el elemento que vas a mover y a que posicion, tienes que intercambiar sus valores de la propiedad `posicion` y finalmente hacer un `.sort` sobre el array resultante para asegurar el orden en base a las nuevas posiciones.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    posicion: 1,
    nombre: 'televisor'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    posicion: 2,
    nombre: 'celular'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    posicion: 3,
    nombre: 'cama'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    posicion: 4,
    nombre: 'laptop'
  }
];

const ordenarItems = (index, value) =>
  data
    .map((item, i) => {
      if (item.posicion === value) {
        return {
          ...item,
          posicion: index
        };
      }

      if (i + 1 === index) {
        return {
          ...item,
          posicion: value
        };
      }

      return item;
    })
    .sort((a, b) => (a.posicion > b.posicion ? 1 : -1));

console.log(ordenarItems(3, 2));
```